# Why does the alpha version of Aurelia load slowly?

Tags: aurelia

I wrote a minimal test page to try out Aurelia.

http://www.andrewgolightly.com/

GitHub: https://github.com/magician11/ag-landingpage

My last test, showed it took 55 seconds to load the page with 135 requests.

It seems I need to bundle the jspm_packages directory first so that the 543KB gets downloaded at once.. and not in pieces.

So given I followed this example: http://aurelia.io/get-started.html

How do I bundle the packages? It's not clear to me from https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Production-Workflows

And then what do I update in my index.html file? And I'll still need to include the jspm_packages folder as I reference it in the head, right?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jspm_packages/npm/font-awesome@4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Thanks.

**Update**

The team is working on bundling..

From Rob Eisenberg: "We aren’t finished with our bundling support just yet. We’re working on it."

Comment: There is bundling in [this repo](https://github.com/YoloDev/mimosa-aurelia-skeleton) which is done using `jspm bundle` and you can see the command for that in the [Snap CI log](https://snap-ci.com/YoloDev/mimosa-aurelia-skeleton/branch/master/logs/defaultPipeline/60/Deploy?back_to=build_history) near the bottom `jspm bundle app/main + app/bundle + core-js lib/app.js --inject`

Comment: Thanks @Sean I updated the question to include a link to the code on GitHub. I then ran the command `jspm bundle src/app --minify` which built a build.js file. But then got stuck on how to update the bottom of the index.html file

Comment: If you use the `--inject` parameter on `jspm bundle`, it will add the bundle config to your jspm `config.js` file and then the SystemJS loader will automagically pick that up without you needing to modify any HTML.

Comment: Ok, so I ran `jspm bundle src/app --minify --inject` It did add code to the config.js file. Then on running `gulp watch` again I got ` Potentially unhandled rejection [2] TypeError: Error loading "github:aurelia/bootstrapper@0.9.3" at http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/bootstrapper@0.9.3.js
Cannot redefine property: name` And the page then failed to load.

Comment: I have a repo [here](https://github.com/SAAirey/aurelia-skeleton-navigation-bundling) that demonstrates bundling with the skeleton app and an explanation of what the steps are to get it all working. The basic gist of it is that jspm needs to know the whole chain to include the right files in the bundle and if there are no references from your `app.js` (or another `import`ed file) then it won't include the correct files and some will ultimately be missing. Then after that is done you may need to include additional dependencies in your `package.json`.

Comment: If you can follow the guide in the readme for that repo then I will re-create it here so we have an eternal SO question for it. Not many people are going to go digging on github I would guess hehe :D

Comment: I wrote a blog article covering this here: http://www.foursails.co/blog/aurelia-bundling/

Answer (score 14):

This question was posted at a *very* early time but we do have a strategy now in place that works with jspm and system.js loader for bundling.  As a note it's not that the framework is slow it's that the loading of assets was taking a while early on due to the high number of requests (and that you probably didn't have gzip enabled)

I've copied this from my blog post on the subject - http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-for-aurelia-bundling-and-minification/

#### Requirements

1. Understand that a [jspm bundle](https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/wiki/Production-Workflows#creating-a-bundle) command is used to let [system.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), our module loader, know to load the bundle
2. Understand this only covers the JavaScript files (for now)

#### Create a new bundle

1. Open your terminal and navigate to your `skeleton-navigation` folder.
2. Open your config.js in your text editor
3. Run this command -

   ```
   jspm bundle '*' + aurelia-skeleton-navigation/* + aurelia-bootstrapper + aurelia-http-client + aurelia-dependency-injection + aurelia-router dist/app-bundle.js --inject --minify
   ```

#### Breakdown

```
// Create a bundle
jspm bundle 
    // Bundle all of these paths
    // from my config.js 
    '*' +
    aurelia-skeleton-navigation/* +
    aurelia-bootstrapper +
    aurelia-http-client + 
    aurelia-dependency-injection + 
    aurelia-router
    // Create the bundle here
    // with this name
    dist/app-bundle.js
    // These modifiers tell the bundle
    // to both minify and then inject
    // the bundle
    --inject
    --minify
```

#### Additional notes on bundling

1. If you are serving in production you may want to look at setting `baseUrl` in your [config.js](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/wiki/Configuration-Options#bundle) like that
2. To unbundle and serve files individually use `jspm unbundle`
3. Since we used the `--inject` modifier system.js should pick up on our bundle and serve it without changing our script path in index.html
4. You can add more files by using `+ {filename}` in the bundle area

Comment: thanks for the well written answer !

even if Aurelia is not yet production ready , having a build strategy to play with , even early on, is really helpfull

Comment: Is there a way to set it up to use `bundle-sfx` to create a single distributable script file?

Comment: a new official way is to use Aurelia-CLI: http://blog.durandal.io/2015/06/23/bundling-an-aurelia-application/

Answer (score 9):

### 2016 Update

The official toolkit for bundling aurelia applications can be installed via npm using `npm install --save-dev aurelia-bundler`.

Once installed, you can set up a gulp task for handling the bundle / unbundle process. A basic example of a task looks like this:

**build/tasks/bundle.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');

var config = {
  bundles: {
    'dist/app-build': {
      includes: [
        '**/*.js'
      ],
      options: {
        minify: true
      }
    }
  }
};
gulp.task('bundle', ['build', 'unbundle'], function() {
  return bundler.bundle(config);
});
gulp.task('unbundle', function() {
  return bundler.unbundle(config);
});
```

I've written a more in-depth article here: http://www.foursails.co/blog/aurelia-bundling/

The official documentation can be found here: https://github.com/aurelia/bundler

Comment: This article is good for production bundling, not working for development. I have lot of dependencies in development, has to wait more than 1 min see my changes. Please share development workflow also.

Comment: In general, you don't want to bundle for development. Bundling is strictly for making your application production ready.

Comment: Agree.... bundling should be done by your CI and not end developers (although I recommend running your bundle / unbundle targets if you are changing dependencies before commiting).  Bundle for production or demo.  Not for dev

Answer (score 4):

There is a GitHub repository that includes an r.js bundling strategy for the Aurelia AMD target build, as well as sample projects for using the bundle in Visual Studio with TypeScript (including an aurelia.d.ts TypeScript type definition file).

- [repo](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript)
- [bundling with r.js](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#bundling)
- [aurelia.d.ts](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript/blob/master/skel-nav-esri-vs-ts/skel-nav-esri-vs-ts/typings/aurelia/aurelia.d.ts)

using this strategy should dramatically reduce your load time as it will be loading one file instead of many files.

Comment: its worth nothing that a more official aurelia build strategy is coming

Comment: agreed !! :)  this is a sample and an experiment