# Aurelia javascript dependencies loading time

Tags: aurelia

I've just downloaded the Skeleton sample app from Aurelia.
The "gulp build" output still loads hundreds of JavaScript files in the browser. Am I missing something ?
Can we use Browserify (or something close) to merge all of these js files in a single one, or is it by design ?

Edit : [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258956/why-does-the-alpha-version-of-aurelia-load-slowly) got precious answers.

Comment: Yes please check into jspm Aurelia bundling, google or in gitter

Comment: You're right. I didn't use the exact same terms to describe this very same issue though. Added a link to that question too.
There's an issue on GitHub too : https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/issues/13

Things should be much smoother in a few months or weeks.